# How to install Haproxy 1.5 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: installation, raspberry-pi, haproxy, raspbian

Using apt-get I'm only able to install haproxy version 1.4 or lower, but I need to install haproxy 1.5. I'm running a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian. Could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

While reading up on load balancing a Raspberry Pi myself I stumbled across this:

https://raspberry-hosting.com/en/faq/where-can-i-find-actual-haproxy-and-keepalived-deb-packages-raspberry-pi-and-how-i-install-high

I hope it helps.